# Dynamically disable creation of session cookies with spring security

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-security

My application is using spring (and spring security) over tomcat 7.
I have two kinds of roles - ROLE_1 and ROLE_2, and two website that access my single application (CORS calls).

I want to be able to use two browser tabs: one, website1 with ROLE_1 and second on website2 with ROLE_2.

The problem is that if website1 access the server, he gets session id associtated with ROLE_1. When website2 access the server, it overwrites the session id, and then - ROLE_1 can do nothing as it doesn't have the permission he needs.

In fact, website2 and ROLE_2 doens't really need session.

So I need a way to either -
1. Remove the session id from the response object of website2 / ROLE_2 (not deleting the session cookie, as it's been used by website1. Just removing it from the response).

2. Set different session cookie name for differnt kinds of roles. Please note that I can't use the static approaches (such as sessionCookieName="my_session_name" in context.xml), as both wesites share the same server.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you going to maintain login state without session?

See Spring Session for allowing multi-sign-in

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I can authenticate every request using Authorization header